# How change axis/coordinates/xy order for a particular layer in a Map?

Tags: openlayers-2

Currently WMS requests are like:

> ....&BBOX=*minX*,**minY**,*maxX*,**maxY**&....

I need one layer to have this order:

> ....&BBOX=**minY**,*minX*,**maxY**,*maxX*&....

... while remaining 99% of the map layers use the old order.

**UPDATE:**

All layers are in EPSG:3346.

WMS version can be 1.1.1 or 1.3.0 I guess since I have successfuly made some mock requets for both versions.

Don't know the server type. This layer needs to be retrieved from [Sentinel Hub](http://www.sentinel-hub.com/apps/wms/wms-parameters)

Comment: what projection are your layers in? which version of WMS are you using? Do you know the Server type?

Comment: @iant added info to the question.

Comment: Strictly makes no difference for WMS 1.1.1 and WMS 1.3.0, both use minx, miny, maxx, maxy for the bounding box.  The issue us which axis is regarded as x and y!  The order of the axes as specified in the CRS never changed, the issue is that WMS 1.3.0 uses the axis order (X, Y) specified in the CRS, whereas WMS 1.1.1 said that X would always be longitude (easting), and this isn't always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlooked `yx` property in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html)
Had to add `yx: {'EPSG:3346' : true}` and specify `version: '1.3.0'`