# OpenLayers flip coordinate order for BBOX WMS request

Tags: openlayers, wms

I have a WMS layer which have a different axis-orientation to the one that OpenLayers sends out in the BBOX-request.

Openlayers uses the BBOX (minx,miny,maxx,maxy): `BBOX=1438239.124213878%2C7895639.273745567%2C1448023.0638343806%2C7905423.213366069`

But to get my map-tiles I have to swap the axis-order to this (miny,minx,maxy,maxy):

```
BBOX=7895639.273745567%2C1438239.124213878%2C7905423.213366069%2C1448023.0638343806
```

The x and y should change order in the request. Is there any simple solution to this?

I´ve tried to read other questions, but most requests is to change the coordinate system, which I´m not interested in.

Also, the same question I have is posted here: [How change axis/coordinates/xy order for a particular layer in a Map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257469/how-change-axis-coordinates-xy-order-for-a-particular-layer-in-a-map)

But that is referring to OpenLayers 2.

Comment: Which coordinate system you are using, and have you defined WMS to use version 1.1 or 1.3?

Comment: The WMS can be dinfined in a lot of different CRS, but to make it easy the coordinatesystem is currently 3857. And yes, the version is defined:

source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'Myurl',
                params: {
      'VERSION': '1.3.0',
                    'LAYERS': 'wmslayer', 
      'TILED': true,
                    'STYLES': '',
      'FORMAT': 'image/png' 
                }
            })

Comment: Is your place of interest in the Southern Sweden or close to the Western coast of India?

Comment: Sweden is correct

Comment: In that case the BBOX that is created by OpenLayers is correct and you shoud fix the non-standard WMS service instead https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=1438239&y=7895639&z=4&layer=streets

Comment: @user30184 That's making a big assumption the developer of a client application has access to the potentially third party service to fix it. It might be better to test if it uses standard xy format in a 1.1 request and if it does configure OpenLayers to use 1.1 requests.

Comment: @Mike There shouldn't be any difference between WMS 1.3.0 and WMS 1.1.1 for EPSG:3857.  WMS 1.3.0 just says use the axes order defined by the CRS.  so it could be lat/long or long/lat, or easting/northing or northing/easting, whilst as you say WMS 1.1.1 ignored the defined axes order and said it was always long/lat or easting/northing.     EPSG:3857 is easting/northing, so WMS version should make no difference.  If the WMS has the wrong axes, then the server is wrong and needs fixing or the error needs resolving in OpenLayers somehow.

Comment: @nmtoken True there shoudn't be a difference but if for BBOX=7895639.273745567%2C1438239.124213878%2C7905423.213366069%2C1448023.0638343806 the server is returning data for Sweden there is a problem with the server and if the data is being served from a third-party system that needs to be worked around somehow at the client end. If switching to 1.1 requests makes the server respond as expected that would be by far the easiest workaround, so it is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the server to fix the non-standard WMS you can use a custom tile url function to swap the bbox coordinates.  This should work for a standard tile grid with square tiles and centered at [0,0].

```
var defaultUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction().bind(source);
source.setTileUrlFunction( function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
    var coord = ol.extent.getCenter(this.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord)).reverse();
    var newTileCoord = this.getTileGrid().getTileCoordForCoordAndZ(coord, tileCoord[0]);
    return defaultUrlFunction(newTileCoord, pixelRatio, projection);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Openlayers uses the BBOX (minx,miny,maxx,maxy)

So does WMS version 1.3.0:

> 7.2.4.6.8 BoundingBox
>
> WMS service metadata shall declare one or more bounding boxes (as defined in 6.7.4) for each Layer.
> A Bounding Box metadata element may either be stated explicitly or may be inherited from a parent Layer. In XML,
> the  metadata element includes the following attributes:
>
> ⎯ CRS indicates the Layer CRS that applies to this bounding box.
>
> ⎯ minx, miny, maxx, maxy indicate the limits of the bounding box using the axis units and order of the specified CRS.
>
> ⎯ resx and resy (optional) indicate the spatial resolution of the data comprising the layer in those same units.

And indeed WMS 1.1.1:

> 7.2.3.6 BBOX
>
> The required BBOX parameter allows a Client to request a particular Bounding Box.
> Bounding Boxes are defined in the Basic Service Elements section. The value of the
> BBOX parameter in a GetMap request is a list of comma-separated numbers of the form
> "minx,miny,maxx,maxy".

The difference between the two standards is not the order of the x,y in the request, it's the potential difference between the definition of which axis (Easting/Northing, Latitude/Longitude, ...) constitutes x or y.

In WMS 1.1.1  the axis order is set as X=longitude (easting) and Y=latitude (northing), even if the actual axis order specified in the coordinate reference system is the other way around...  In WMS 1.3.0 the axis order is specified according to the coordinate reference system definition.

So...

[urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857) defines its axes as first axis **"easting (X)"** and second axis **"northing (Y)"**

Assuming you are using EPSG::3857, there should be no difference to your application if you use a WMS 1.1.1 or WMS 1.3.0.

Assuming OpenLayers is expecting x=Longitude/Easting, and you are using EPSG::3857, then if your data is displaying in the wrong location, the issue is with the WMS.

Comment: Yes, not all WMS comply with standards, and if it's not your own service and you need to use it that's a problem.  As mentioned in the question OpenLayers 2 had a one line solution which is not available in OL3+.